# Get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when placing combobox in Tabcontainer

Tags: asp.net

I have an Ajaxtoolkit Tabcontainer with two tabs which second tab enabled is False.
I have placed a Combobox AjaxToolikit control in  the second tab. but when a post back is occurred to server just in IE browser I get following error.
But in Firefox I have no problem and every thing works properly.
what's wrong?

this is my code:

```
     <ul>
          <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnNew" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CssImages/new_document.png"
                            ToolTip="New" Width="20px" OnClick="BtnNew_Click" /></li>
</ul>


 <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
    <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Tab1" HeaderText="xx">
    <ContentTemplate>
    xx
    </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
    <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" HeaderText="yy"  Enabled="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
    dsds <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>loblob</asp:ListItem>
        </cc1:ComboBox>
    </ContentTemplate>

    </cc1:TabPanel>
    </cc1:TabContainer>
```

Error:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +168
   AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +57
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +690
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1743
```

Comment: Posting your code will help immensely in getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that IE doesn't submitting to server disabled form elements as well as elements in disabled container. There are a lot of ways to fix this available. The most simple approach is to disable ComboBox control as well and enable it with parent tab control. 
More general decision is to fix ComboBox sources in AjaxControlToolkit library. To do this you need to download library sources and change first rows of `LoadPostData` method in `Server/AjaxControlToolkit/ComboBox/ComboBox.cs` file as below:

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
{
    if (!Enabled || postCollection.GetValues(HiddenFieldControl.UniqueID) == null)
        return false;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem, even though I was not using any hidden panels/controls.
It turned out that the designer.cs in behind was generating ComboBox controls for me EVEN THOUGH THEY WERE COMMENTED OUT in the .aspx .

Remove my commented-out experimental/reminder code, everything worked fine.

The generated control acted as if it were hidden -- same exception popped up upon postback.